# WPF - PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown finding the visual owning control of e.OriginalSource

Tags: c#, wpf, events, visual-tree, logical-tree

Very simple question.

I have attached to the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event.   I know this event Tunnels so the first item in the visual tree is going to get flagged as the e.OriginalSource.

Example:

I have a Grid named "MainGrid".  This Grid contains a label.

If I setup a PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event on that grid and I click on the the label, the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event will be triggered.

The MouseButtonEventArgs for this contains an OriginalSource (e.OriginalSource).  Depending on where I click inside of the label, this might be a border...this might be a textblock or this might be a border.

I want to walk the visual tree and find "MainGrid".  I know of the recursive ways to do this, but what if I don't know the type of the owner.  I only know I want to find the owner (i.e. this needs to be generic).

Something like "e.OriginalSource.ORIGINAL_OWNER"

Will gladly elaborate if this is not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are just looking for [`e.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.source.aspx)?